# Divs not taking up full height

Tags: css

I have a 9-box with a div structure like so:

```
<div class="NBWrapper">
    <div class="NBTopRow">
        <div class="NBLeft" />
        <div class="NBRight" />
        <div class="NBMiddle" />
    </div>
    <div class="NBMiddleRow">
        <div class="NBLeft">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="NBRight">&nbsp</div>
        <div class="NBMiddle">SharePoint WebPart goes here</div>
    </div>
    <div class="NBBottomRow">
        <div class="NBLeft" />
        <div class="NBRight" />
        <div class="NBMiddle" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And have the following CSS Rules:

```
.NBTopRow .NBLeft {
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: left;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-top-left.png') no-repeat;
}
.NBTopRow .NBRight {
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: right;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-top-right.png') no-repeat;
}
.NBTopRow .NBMiddle {
margin-left: 18px;
margin-right: 18px;
height: 18px;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-top.png') repeat-x;
}
.NBMiddleRow .NBLeft {
width: 18px;
float: left;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-left.png') repeat-y;
}
.NBMiddleRow .NBRight {
width: 18px;
float: right;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-right.png') repeat-y;
}
.NBMiddleRow .NBMiddle {
margin-left: 18px;
margin-right: 18px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.NBMiddleRow {
height: 100%;
}
.NBBottomRow .NBLeft {
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: left;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-bottom-left.png') no-repeat;
}
.NBBottomRow .NBRight {
height: 18px;
width: 18px;
float: right;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-bottom-right.png') no-repeat;
}
.NBBottomRow .NBMiddle {
margin-left: 18px;
margin-right: 18px;
height: 18px;
background: transparent url('/Style Library/Images/qp-bg-bottom.png') repeat-x;
}
```

Everything is in the right place and has the right attributes however, the NBLeft and NBRight elements of the middle row are not taking up any height. Using height:100% does not have any effect.

I have added &nbsp and still nothing.

I am usually good with this sort of stuff, but I am stumped. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: that height will depend on the parent element. so if you want to set the height to 100% for NBLeft and NBRight you must first set NBTopRow, NBMiddleRow, and NBBottomRow. then in turn if you want those at 100% height you must set NBWrapper height. also, you cannot self-close the div element.

Comment: The divs are generated like that by sharepoint, and for the top and bottom rows they are fine. Its only for the left and right in the middle row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i ended up doing was restructuring the divs:

```
<div class="NBWrapper">
<div class="NBTopRow">
    <div class="NBLeft" />
    <div class="NBMiddle" />
    <div class="NBRight" />
</div>
<div class="NBMiddleRow">
    <div class="NBLeft">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="NBMiddle">SharePoint WebPart goes here</div>
    <div class="NBRight">&nbsp</div>
</div>
<div class="NBBottomRow">
    <div class="NBLeft" />
    <div class="NBMiddle" />
    <div class="NBRight" />
</div>
</div>
```

Taking away the floats and the margins in the attributes and adding this:

```
.NBWrapper {
display: table;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0;
width: 100%;
}

.NBTopRow, .NBMiddleRow, .NBBottomRow {
display: table-row;
}

.NBLeft, .NBRight, .NBMiddle {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

You might ask, why not just use a table? SharePoint 2010 may use less of them, but but its still tables all the way down. I prefer using div structures.

Answer (score 0):

your NBleft & NBright are self closing make it like `<div></div>`

Comment: The only way to do that with sharepoint is to put &nbsp in a literal control and add that to the panel that is generating this div structure.
I have already done that with no results.

Answer (score 0):

Are self closing divs supported correctly in the HTML Version you're using? You could try using  instead?

I can see...

```
<div class="NBMiddle">SharePoint WebPart goes here<div>
```

Should be ...

```
<div class="NBMiddle">SharePoint WebPart goes here</div>
```

Other thing to try is overflow:auto in the CSS class of the div givin you trouble. As long as the div has content, the CSS will make sure it's displayed.

Comment: Would change the self closing divs like svalbard suggests

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake when I put in the question. The div structure doesnt actually have that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but does the below help? I've added borders to everything so you can see what's happening.

The HTML...

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bla.css" >
</head>

<body>

<div class="NBWrapper">
    <div class="NBrow">
        <div class="NBcell">Top Left</div>
        <div class="NBcell">Top Middle</div>
        <div class="NBcell">Top Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="NBrow">
        <div class="NBcellFullHeight">Middle Left</div>
        <div class="NBcellFullHeight">Middle Middle</div>
        <div class="NBcellFullHeight">Middle Right</div>
    </div>

    <div class="NBrow">
        <div class="NBcell">Bottom Left</div>
        <div class="NBcell">Bottom Middle</div>
        <div class="NBcell">Bottom Right</div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then the CSS...

```
.NBWrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

.NBcell {
    width: 266px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.NBrow {
    float: left;
    width: 804px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.NBcellFullHeight {
    width: 266px;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

Comment: This is user control generated in code for a SharePoint 2010 webpart. It has to allow for dynamic placement in webpart zones that could be any width, and be able to expand vertically depending on the content. I cant assign explicit heights or widths to anything except the corners (18x18), the top/bottom borders (height: 18px) and the left/right borders (width:18px).

The top and bottom borders both render correctly, however the same cannot be said for the left and right borders. They have the correct width, but are of height 0.